# RIA Services SP2 issue

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have a Silverlight 4 application which uses RIA Services.
I updated Ria Services SP1 to SP2.
In my local pc my application works without any issues but when I deploy it to a server and I try to use it I get a very annoying message:
"HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly"

Before my application worked perfectly I just applied the ria services sp2 upgrade.

Ria Servcies is not installed on the server but the necessary dlls are in the bin folder.

Anybody can help me?

l.

Answer (score 1):

Install RIA on the server... that way you can be sure all the correct DLLs are installed and registered in the right place on the machine.

You'll need to run msiexec with SERVER=TRUE
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426912(v=vs.91).aspx